# Fetch a particular part of the url in python

Tags: python, string, list, url, urlparse

I am using python and trying to fetch a particular part of the url as below

```
from urlparse import urlparse as ue

url = "https://www.google.co.in"
img_url = ue(url).hostname
```

**Result**

```
www.google.co.in
```

**case1**:

Actually i will have a number of urls(stored in a list or some where else), so what i want is, need to find the `domain name` as above in the url and fetch the part after `www.` and before `.co.in`, that is the string starts after `first dot` and before `second dot` which results only `google` in the present scenario.

So suppose the url given is url given is `www.gmail.com`, i should fetch only `gmail` in that, so what ever the url given, the code should fetch the part thats starts with first dot and before second dot.

**case2:**

Also some urls may be given directly like this `domain.com, stackoverflow.com` without `www` in the url, in that cases it should fetch only `stackoverflow` and  `domain`.

Finally my intention is to fetch the main name from the url that `gmail, stackoverflow, google` like so.....

Generally if i have one url i can use `list slicing` and will fetch the string, but i will have a number of ulrs, so need to fetch the wanted part like mentioned above dynamically

Can anyone please let me know how to satisfy the above concept ?

Comment: What about something like "login.gmail.com.hk"? Also return "gmail"?

Comment: yeah absolutely , thats what i mean , but i dont know whether that possible to fetch or not in this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, at the end, *domains* holds a list of domains you expected.

```
import urlparse
urls = [
    'https://www.google.com', 
    'http://stackoverflow.com',
    'http://www.google.co.in',
    'http://domain.com',
    ]
hostnames = [urlparse.urlparse(url).hostname for url in urls]
hostparts = [hostname.split('.') for hostname in hostnames]
domains = [p[0] == 'www' and p[1] or p[0] for p in hostparts]
print domains # ==> ['google', 'stackoverflow', 'google', 'domain']
```

#### Discussion

1. First, we extract the host names from the list of URLs using `urlparse.urlparse()`. The *hostnames* list looks like this:

   [ 'www.google.com', 'stackoverflow.com, ... ]
2. In the next line, we break each host into parts, using the dot as the separator. Each item in the hostparts looks like this:

   [ ['www', 'google', 'com'], ['stackoverflow', 'com'], ... ]
3. The interesting work is in the next line. This line says, "if the first part before the dot is *www*, then the domain is the second part (p[1]). Otherwise, the domain is the first part (p[0]). The *domains* list looks like this:

   [ 'google', 'stackoverflow', 'google', 'domain' ]
4. My code does not know how to handle login.gmail.com.hk. I hope someone else can solve this problem as I am late for bed. **Update**: Take a look at the *tldextract* by John Kurkowski, which should do what you want.

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this because the real solution is to use the library you mention: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract . You should change your answer and remove the suggested code, because that suggestion will only cover a small subset of the possible names out there. Promote tldextract instead ;-)

Comment: There are systems such as ones at my workplace that we are not allowed to install third-party packages such as tldextract. This is where my solution come in. In addition to down-voting, you might want to show instances where my solution does not work, along with suggestion to fix.

Comment: I've spent several years working for browser vendors (Opera, recently Mozilla) and believe me: this is a really hard problem that we've wanted a solution to many times. We didn't really rise to the challenge until Mozilla set up http://publicsuffix.org/ - and even now it seems rather odd to ship all those bytes of information to solve a problem that looks so simple. Sorry, I will not list cases where it fails and attempt to resolve them. The domain name system is too complicated :-/

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just do this:

```
from urlparse import urlparse as ue
urls = ['https://www.google.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com']
parsed = []
for url in urls:
    decoded = ue(url).hostname
    if decoded.startswith('www.'):
        decoded = ".".join(decoded.split('.')[1:])
    parsed.append(decoded.split('.')[0])
#parsed is now your parsed list of hostnames
```

Also, you might want to change the if statement in the for loop, because some domains might start with other things that you would want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a set of predefined toplevel doamains?

```
import re
from urlparse import urlparse

#Fake top level domains... EG: co.uk, co.in, co.cc
TOPLEVEL = [".co.[a-zA-Z]+", ".fake.[a-zA-Z]+"]

def TLD(rgx, host, max=4): #4 = co.name
        match = re.findall("(%s)" % rgx, host, re.IGNORECASE)
        if match: 
            if len(match[0].split(".")[1])<=max:
                return match[0]
        else:
            return False

parsed = []
urls = ["http://www.mywebsite.xxx.asd.com", "http://www.dd.test.fake.uk/asd"]
for url in urls:
    o = urlparse(url)
    h = o.hostname
    for j in range(len(TOPLEVEL)):
        TL = TLD(TOPLEVEL[j], h)
        if TL: 
            name = h.replace(TL, "").split(".")[-1]
            parsed.append(name)
            break
        elif(j+1==len(TOPLEVEL)): 
            parsed.append(h.split(".")[-2])
            break

print parsed
```

It's a bit hacky, and maybe cryptic for some, but it does the trick, and nothing more has to be done :)